# No WYSIWYG for wiki in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

From googling it looks like the VSTS wiki editor had a nice WYSIWYG editor. My project for VSTS is found at the *.visualstudio.com URL. However, it does not seem to have a WYSIWYG editor. The [wiki add on in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=agile-extensions.wiki) (when it was still in beta) shows a nice WYSIWYG editor, but does the final version only have a markup editor?

It's just that the markup editor isn't very user friendly for project managers and the like. I thought the purpose of the wiki was to be a credible alternative to [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29) and others?

Comment: This didn't make it into the product. Not entirely sure why. Pinged the Product team, maybe they'll comment.

Comment: Ah, hopefully it makes it in as an update..

Comment: Not mentioned in the feature timeline at the moment though.

Comment: I won't hold my breath then :( thank you for the help, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently we do not have plans to support WYSIWYG editing. We do support a side-by-side edit and preview experience that can help you in reviewing content as you type.

In VSTS, we standardized on a common Markdown format for editing that helps us to host richer content across all Markdown experiences. E.g. just this sprint we shipped mathematical formulas powered by LaTeX and also integrated Markdown rendering in code and wiki so all the rich capabilities that you have seen in the wiki so far will also be available when you create README.MD files in code.

I will be blogging about all this shortly at *[Microsoft DevOps Blog, tag wiki](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/tag/wiki/)*. Having said that, I am closely monitoring this User Voice entry to enable WYSIWYG editing in wikis: *[Wysiwyg editing in Wiki](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31261051-wysiwyg-editing-in-wiki)*. I suggest you to upvote it so that it will help to prioritize this feature ask.

I am sorry that you are not getting a WYSIWYG editing experience yet, but I am all ears to more feedback.

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks for pinging me for this :)

Comment: I guess the uservoice for this topic moved here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/379602/wysiwyg-editing-in-wiki.html